# Delay of mail delivery - Hosted exchange provider

Tags: email, exchange, exchange-2007, web-hosting

I recently signed up to a new hosted email provider.
When I send mail (from OWA, OR Outlook) there is a delay of up to 3 minutes from when i send the message, to when it's received (in my gmail account for example)

I've listed the headers below.

Is there anything I can advise my new email host to do?
My previous email host delivers within 5 seconds!!

**New email provider:**

```
Delivered-To: ****.*****@******.co.uk.test-google-a.com
Received: by 10.223.120.148 with SMTP id d20cs333125far; Mon, 30 Nov 2009
 08:49:43 -0800 (PST)
Received: by 10.213.106.202 with SMTP id y10mr4864870ebo.35.1259599782838;
 Mon, 30 Nov 2009 08:49:42 -0800 (PST)
Return-Path: 
Received: from relay005.apm-internet.net (relay005.apm-internet.net
 [85.119.248.8]) by mx.google.com with SMTP id
 26si13016480ewy.43.2009.11.30.08.49.42; Mon, 30 Nov 2009 08:49:42 -0800 (PST)
Received-SPF: neutral (google.com: 85.119.248.8 is neither permitted nor
 denied by best guess record for domain of ****@*******.com)
 client-ip=85.119.248.8;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com; spf=neutral (google.com: 85.119.248.8
 is neither permitted nor denied by best guess record for domain of
 ****@*******.com) smtp.mail=****@*******.com
Received: (qmail 63915 invoked from network); 30 Nov 2009 16:49:41 -0000
Received: from unknown (HELO mx-out-manc2.simplymailsolutions.com)
 (88.151.129.22) by relay005.apm-internet.net with SMTP; 30 Nov 2009 16:49:42
 -0000
X-APM-IP: 88.151.129.22
X-APM-Score: 4
Received-SPF: none (relay005.apm-internet.net: domain at alexjamesbrown.com
 does not designate permitted sender hosts)
Received: from [10.1.20.1] (helo=win-s-manc1.shared.ifeltd.com) by
 mx-out-manc2.simplymailsolutions.com with esmtp (Exim 4.63) (envelope-from
 ) id 1NF9QZ-0005By-Hw for ****.*****@******.co.uk;
 Mon, 30 Nov 2009 16:48:46 +0000
Received: from sha-exch8.shared.ifeltd.com ([10.1.20.8]) by
 win-s-manc1.shared.ifeltd.com with Microsoft SMTPSVC(6.0.3790.3959); Mon, 30
 Nov 2009 16:48:34 +0000
Received: from sha-exch9.shared.ifeltd.com ([10.1.20.9]) by
 sha-exch8.shared.ifeltd.com with Microsoft SMTPSVC(6.0.3790.3959); Mon, 30
 Nov 2009 16:48:34 +0000
Received: from SHA-EXCH13.shared.ifeltd.com (10.1.20.13) by
 sha-exch9.shared.ifeltd.com (10.1.20.9) with Microsoft SMTP Server (TLS) id
 8.1.393.1; Mon, 30 Nov 2009 16:48:25 +0000
Received: from SHA-EXCH12.shared.ifeltd.com ([fe80::ecba:36d0:eec5:c928]) by
 SHA-EXCH13.shared.ifeltd.com ([fe80::212b:916c:70c7:a4e5%11]) with mapi; Mon,
 30 Nov 2009 16:48:05 +0000
From: Alex Brown 
To: "****.*****@*****.co.uk" 
Date: Mon, 30 Nov 2009 16:48:04 +0000
Subject: testing
Thread-Topic: testing
Thread-Index: AQHKcdzZg4oiDsOYIEio/7k6bCk8BQ==
Message-ID: 
Accept-Language: en-US, en-GB
Content-Language: en-GB
X-MS-Has-Attach: 
X-MS-TNEF-Correlator: 
acceptlanguage: en-US, en-GB
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="us-ascii"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
MIME-Version: 1.0
X-OriginalArrivalTime: 30 Nov 2009 16:48:34.0235 (UTC)
 FILETIME=[F48178B0:01CA71DC]
```

**Here are the headers using my previous exchange host:**

```
Delivered-To: ****.*****@******.co.uk.test-google-a.com
Received: by 10.223.120.148 with SMTP id d20cs333076far; Mon, 30 Nov 2009
 08:48:35 -0800 (PST)
Received: by 10.213.2.70 with SMTP id 6mr4797985ebi.25.1259599715739; Mon, 30
 Nov 2009 08:48:35 -0800 (PST)
Return-Path: 
Received: from relay005.apm-internet.net (relay005.apm-internet.net
 [85.119.248.8]) by mx.google.com with SMTP id
 26si13030993ewy.23.2009.11.30.08.48.35; Mon, 30 Nov 2009 08:48:35 -0800 (PST)
Received-SPF: neutral (google.com: 85.119.248.8 is neither permitted nor
 denied by best guess record for domain of ****@*********.com)
 client-ip=85.119.248.8;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com; spf=neutral (google.com: 85.119.248.8
 is neither permitted nor denied by best guess record for domain of
 ****@*********.com) smtp.mail=****@*********.com
Received: (qmail 60920 invoked from network); 30 Nov 2009 16:48:34 -0000
Received: from unknown (HELO MTAb.MsExchange2007.com) (89.31.236.50) by
 relay005.apm-internet.net with SMTP; 30 Nov 2009 16:48:35 -0000
X-APM-IP: 89.31.236.50
X-APM-Score: 1
Received-SPF: none (relay005.apm-internet.net: domain at alexjamesbrown.com
 does not designate permitted sender hosts)
Received: from EXHUB02.SL.local (no.ptr.hostlogic.biz [89.31.236.28]) by
 MTAb.MsExchange2007.com (Spam Firewall) with ESMTP id B677A34FE0F for
 ; Mon, 30 Nov 2009 16:48:33 +0000 (GMT)
Received: from EXHUB02.SL.local (no.ptr.hostlogic.biz [89.31.236.28]) by
 MTAb.MsExchange2007.com with ESMTP id 8X5B8V4tExVzoNyU for
 ; Mon, 30 Nov 2009 16:48:34 +0000 (GMT)
Received: from EXCCR03STORE.SL.local ([10.0.0.2]) by EXHUB02.SL.local
 ([192.168.92.64]) with mapi; Mon, 30 Nov 2009 16:48:31 +0000
From: Alex James Brown 
To: "****.*****@******.co.uk" 
Date: Mon, 30 Nov 2009 16:48:30 +0000
Subject: testing from o
Thread-Topic: testing from o
Thread-Index: AQHKcdzyY1iBFWiol0ykG6xPQUZiTg==
Message-ID: 
Accept-Language: en-US, en-GB
Content-Language: en-GB
X-MS-Has-Attach: 
X-MS-TNEF-Correlator: 
acceptlanguage: en-US, en-GB
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="us-ascii"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
MIME-Version: 1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

It could be a function of how many hops the email is going through now as opposed to how many it went through previously. Each hop is going to add some time to the delivery process. Also, as there's nothing in the RFC's that states any time requirements or even a guarantee of delivery of email you probably need to come to grips with the fact that your email may take a little longer now than it used to. My advice: count the number of hops it's going through now as opposed to what it went through previously and check the timestamp at each hop. This might point you to a hop that's adding some delay to the delivery process.

Comment: I was going to count the hops in both sets of headers, but honestly it was giving me a headache.

Answer (score 0):

The new service may be [greylisting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greylisting).  This can add small delays in mail delivery.

Comment: I've never heard of an email host greylisting it's own users. This wouldn't make sense to me. Why would they greylist email going THROUGH them as opposed to email going TO them. Greylisting, AFAIK, is applied to incoming email from foreign senders, not outgoing email from known senders.

Comment: Ah yeah I missed that part that he was sending to an outside email account.  I somehow read it that it was going in the other direction.  To my knowledge gmail doesn't use greylisting.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a plain number of hops issue or Greylisting. Greylisting causes delay of at least 5 minutes and also it is never used for internal emails. Therefore it is unlikely to be that.

However to confirm, you can try the Online Email Server test at http://www.allaboutspam.com/email-server-test and see if that gives you any clues.